# zmq send with NOBLOCK raise Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: sockets, zeromq, pyzmq

This code will raise Resource temporarily unavailable when call with NOBLOCK:

```
context = zmq.Context()
sender = context.socket(zmq.PUSH)
sender.bind('tcp://*:15556')
sender.send('KeEpAliv', zmq.NOBLOCK)  # this line will throw exception
#sender.send('KeEpAliv')  # this line will ok
```

After read the [docs](http://zeromq.github.io/pyzmq/api/zmq.html#zmq.Socket.send), I found no hints for this. but [docs for recv](http://zeromq.github.io/pyzmq/api/zmq.html#zmq.Socket.recv) explained this flag.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Python wrappers raise `zmq.error.Again` if the underlying C API returns `EAGAIN`.

Now, you should follow to [zmq_send](http://api.zeromq.org/2-1%3azmq-send) documentation, which states:

> ZMQ_NOBLOCK 
>   Specifies that the operation should be performed in
>   non-blocking mode. If the message cannot be queued on the socket, the
>   zmq_send() function shall fail with errno set to EAGAIN.

Also, in the errors section:

> EAGAIN 
>   Non-blocking mode was requested and the message cannot be sent at the moment.

Now, why is it not possible to send any message? On the page describing [PUSH/PULL sockets](http://rfc.zeromq.org/spec:30) we can read the following about the `PUSH` socket:

> SHALL create this queue when a peer connects to it. If this peer disconnects, 
>   the PUSH socket SHALL destroy its queue and SHALL discard any messages it contains.

Before any peer connects to your socket, there's nowhere to send the messages, and there's no queue. Thus only 2 things are possible:

- if you call `send()` in blocking mode, it blocks until a peer connects
- if you call `send()` in non-blocking mode, it raises `zmq.error.Again` to inform you, that there's nothing that could be done with the message and you should try again later.

Note, that you can also get this exception if queues for each of the connected peers are full (`PUSH` socket creates a separate queue for each connected peer).

Comment: Thanks, this give me the hint: `send() in non-blocking mode, it raises zmq.error.Again`.

Comment: so, do I understand correctly that the only way to have such "dynamic queue" when pusher can send many messages before any pullers are connected is via a [queue device](http://api.zeromq.org/2-1:zmq-device#toc3)? or "streamer" device? In fact I have tried the queue device for this (with PUSH-PULL sockets on both sides), it works ok. Just from reading the O'Reily book I expected it to be built into sockets. As I understand only PUSH-PULL sockets don't queue when there is nobody connected?

Comment: that's my understanding, though I haven't touched ZMQ for ages now, things might have changed.